# UCI Puzzle (Simple)

Tags: rebus

UCI Simple Rebus Puzzle depicted in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could also be:

> We see eye to eye. I think this because it says "U C I" and "I C U", so that would be we, and then there are i's, which would make it eye to eye.

Answer (score 3):

Reading it literally:

> You see, I see three eyes. From [Third Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_eye), or maybe [1-2-3 Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-Eye,_Two-Eyes,_and_Three-Eyes).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is wrong, but

> Third Eye Blind

4 i's/eye's sees you, who can't see well, with 4 i's, (cube missing), C squared, and one U, therefore the third exponent is blind/missing?

And, "I see you" backward might imply that you really don't see me.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be:

> I see you and I see eye to eye because of the placement of the i's.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is

> "I See you in the eyes" as the U and C seems to be bordered by I's.